# Need to compare id1 values and value that not in id1 from id2

Tags: sql

I have two tables: `fc` and `ff`.

I need to compare the `id` field in the `ff` table with `id1` and `id2` in `fc` table then print the value of `ff` tables `name` field.

In `ff` table id is matching with `fc` table's `id1` for some values and for remaining values we need to compare with `id2`.

Whatever matching in `id1` values for that `id2` also having different values. So I need to take `id1` values and values that not in `id1` from `id2`.

Please send me with some examples.

Comment: Can you show us your current SQL query, and describe what's wrong with it?

Comment: try to give us a table structure for better help...

Comment: and also some sample data even if not "confidential or proprietary"... just something to give context.  Also, use spaces for between sample column data, not tabs.  tabs don't format nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want??

```
SELECT FF.NAME
FROM FF
LEFT JOIN FC FC1 ON FF.ID = FC1.ID1
LEFT JOIN FC FC2 ON FC.ID = FC2.ID2
AND (
    FC1.ID1 = FC2.ID1
    AND FC1.ID2 = FC2.ID2
    )
WHERE (
    FC1.ID1 IS NULL
    AND FC2.ID2 IS NOT NULL
    )
OR (
    FC1.ID1 IS NOT NULL
    AND FC2.ID2 IS NULL
    )
OR (
    FC1.ID1 IS NOT NULL
    AND FC2.ID2 IS NOT NULL
    )
```

Note : Assuming that pair (ID1,ID2) is unique in table FC